# android - Single RadioButton in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-radiobutton

I have a RecyclerView with item that holds RadioButton only, my adapter creates RecyclerView with some positions - can be 5-10 positions with RadioButton in every position. But these RadioButtons are not in the same RadioGroup because they are all in different RecyclerView positions. Is there any way to set single selection for it?

PS: I found this [Select only one radiobutton in a recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218633/select-only-one-radiobutton-in-a-recyclerview), but it's all about RadioGroups in RecyclerView positions, I have RadioButtons only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can manage it by creating a model class with a `boolean` variable `isChecked`.

when you select a `RadioButton` first do `isChecked = false` for all and then make true for your selected button and then call `notifyDataSetChanged`.

**In adapter** use

```
radioButton.setChecked(list.get(position).isChecked())
```

It will help you definitely.

Comment: what if we have more than 100  or 1000 items in list.

Comment: Yeah, I got it but my RecyclerView constructed from ArrayList with defined ObjectModels in it.

Comment: @SanjayMajoka there will not be any problem if it has  more than 100 items.
this is the easiest way you can do. there is another way that is hold the previous view and unchecked it before and check the new one

Comment: @Den then take a new variable inside `ObjectModels` and manage it with this.

Comment: @Den Use this reference it will help you more https://stackoverflow.com/a/36930230/6676466 In this it is  managing it by holding a previous view of radioButton.

Comment: Thank you, looks like I did it :)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. Following the answer of Vishal Chhodwani I wrote the following solution, hoping it can help other readers.

```
class MyRecycler extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecycler.RecyclerViewHolder> {

    static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.aRadioButton)
        RadioButton rb;

        public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView, int viewType, final Context context) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        } 
    }

    private List<MyModel> list;
    private RadioButton selectedRadioButton;  

    // Constructor and other methods here...

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyRecycler.RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

        RadioButton radioButton = holder.rb;
        radioButton.setChecked(list.get(position).isChecked());

        radioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Set unchecked all other elements in the list, so to display only one selected radio button at a time 
                for(MyModel model: list)
                    model.setChecked(false);

                // Set "checked" the model associated to the clicked radio button
                list.get(position).setChecked(true);

                // If current view (RadioButton) differs from previous selected radio button, then uncheck selectedRadioButton
                if(null != selectedRadioButton && !v.equals(selectedRadioButton))
                    selectedRadioButton.setChecked(false);

                // Replace the previous selected radio button with the current (clicked) one, and "check" it
                selectedRadioButton = (RadioButton) v;
                selectedRadioButton.setChecked(true);                    

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**KOTLIN 2021 Tested**

*No matter with datalist size*

**Single Selection RecyclerView with only RadioButton without RadioGroup and Its Tested**

Declare a RadioButton in a variable In your Adapter class:

```
private var lastCheckedRB: RadioButton? = null
```

Now In your Adapter class onBindViewHolder, Write OnclickListener to RadioButton:

```
holder.YOURRADIOBUTTON.setOnClickListener {
    if (lastCheckedRB!=null){
         lastCheckedRB?.isChecked=false
    }
    lastCheckedRB = holder.YOURRADIOBUTTON
}
```