# Recyclerview get data from radiobutton

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-radiobutton

I want select only one radio button in `recyclerView` and get its data in its `Activity`.

I have gone through following solutions :

- [Single selection in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28972049/8089770)
- [Select only one radiobutton in a recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35218633/9514919)

And I made one solution :

```
private static int lastCheckedPos = -1;

    binding.radioButton.setChecked(mImagesList.get(position).isSelected());
    binding.radioButton.setTag(new Integer(position));

                //for default check in first item
                if(position == 0 && mImagesList.get(0).isSelected() && binding.radioButton.isChecked())
                {
                    radioButton = binding.radioButton;
                    lastCheckedPos = 0;
                }

                binding.radioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        RadioButton cb = (RadioButton)v;
                        int clickedPos = ((Integer)cb.getTag()).intValue();

                        if(cb.isChecked())
                        {
                            if(radioButton != null)
                            {
                                radioButton.setChecked(false);
                                mImagesList.get(lastCheckedPos).setSelected(false);
                            }

                            radioButton = cb;
                            lastCheckedPos = clickedPos;
                        }
                        else
                            radioButton = null;

                        mImagesList.get(clickedPos).setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                    }
                });
```

I have written this in `onBindViewHolder` method.

Now to get data i have written this in `adapter` :

```
public String getUserId() {

        if(lastCheckedPos == -1)
        {
            return null;
        } else {
            return mImagesList.get(lastCheckedPos).getUser_code();
        }
    }
```

And get this in activity :

```
 userId = adapter.getUserId();
```

**But I am not able to get any data in activity. It is always showing null. Also if I click twice on radio button then it deselected.**

Please ask if anything unclear. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace `int clickedPos = ((Integer)cb.getTag()).intValue();` by `int clickedPos =position;`