# Uncheck checked radio button in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to uncheck selected radio button on second click (it is a single selection radio button code)

Below is my code:

```
int row_index = -1;

holder.rbBookOfferText.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        holder.rbBookOfferText.setChecked(true);

        row_index = Integer.parseInt(mDataset.get(position).getTaskId());
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    });

    if (row_index == Integer.parseInt(mDataset.get(position).getTaskId())) {
        holder.rbBookOfferText.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        holder.rbBookOfferText.setChecked(false);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Use `setOnCheckedChangeListener` instead of `setOnClickListener`

Comment: I want to uncheck radio button on second click on same radio button

Comment: @Piyush can you give me example as code?

Comment: @VishalVaishnav so is there a case for all 4 radiobuttons to be unchecked?!!!

Comment: Check [this](https://www.journaldev.com/10251/android-radio-button)

Comment: Hi @forpas this radio buttons come from web service ... so a scenario is that customer can select offers or he doesn't want any offer ... so i want to code for uncheck selected radio button when again click on that radio button

Comment: @VishalVaishnav this is the case where you use Checkbox and not radiobutton.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set **holder.rbBookOfferText.setChecked(true);** programmatically on first click. So, **rbBookOfferText** not unChecked on first click.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer;

```
    holder.tvBookOfferText.setOnClickListener(view -> {

            if (mDataset.get(position).getTaskId().equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(row_index))) {
                holder.tvBookOfferText.setChecked(false);
                row_index = -1;
            } else {
                holder.tvBookOfferText.setChecked(true);
                row_index = Integer.parseInt(mDataset.get(position).getTaskId());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        });

        if (row_index == Integer.parseInt(mDataset.get(position).getTaskId())) {
            holder.tvBookOfferText.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            holder.tvBookOfferText.setChecked(false);
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

To uncheck radio button on second click of same radio button you need to take **all the radio buttons under one radio group**.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Place 3 order of Margherita and on 4th order get $20 off"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
       <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hourly based order"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
      <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Place 3 order of Pugliese and get 4th Pugliese free"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
      <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="40% order off on Place order "
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: This is recyclerview .....I am not using static only 4 radio buttons dude

Comment: Please refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218633/select-only-one-radiobutton-in-a-recyclerview

Comment: totally unrelated answer